# How to retrieve only a predefined number of results in Azure Tables

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to perform an azure table query.
My table (that saves logs) has thousands of rows of data, and it gets populated with more each second.

Right now i have only 1 partition key, but it doesn't affect the next question.

How can i get back lets say only the 100 latest results.

this is my Entity:

```
    public MainServerLogEntity(string Message)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = "mainserverlogs";
        this.RowKey = (DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).ToString();
        this.Message = Message;
        this.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public MainServerLogEntity() { }

    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Right now this is the query i am performing inside a web api i have:

```
    [Route("MainServerLogs")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<MainServerLogEntity> GetMainServerLogs()
    {
        CloudTable table = AzureStorageHelpers.GetWebApiTable(connectionString, "mainserverlogs");
        TableQuery<MainServerLogEntity> query = new TableQuery<MainServerLogEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "mainserverlogs"));

        return table.ExecuteQuery(query);
    }
```

But the problem is that i am getting alot of data, and i am requesting this api every few seconds in order to update the ui.

What should i do? is it possible to define in the query that i only want the 100 first rows? 
If it is not possible then what other technique should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing a .Take(100) on the query like so:

```
[Route("MainServerLogs")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<MainServerLogEntity> GetMainServerLogs()
{
    CloudTable table = AzureStorageHelpers.GetWebApiTable(connectionString, "mainserverlogs");
    TableQuery<MainServerLogEntity> query = new TableQuery<MainServerLogEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "mainserverlogs")).Take(100);

    return table.ExecuteQuery(query);
}
```